# projection into the intersection of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, projection

Is projecting into a set $X$ and then projecting the result into the second set $Y$ the same as projecting into the intersection of $X$ and $Y$?

I am not sure if these information will be needed to answer my question, but just to provide some contextual details.

Let's assume $X=\{x : Ax=0\}$ and $Y=\{y: y\geq 0\}$.

Comment: What is $A$ in the definition of $X$?

Comment: by Ax=b I meant some linear equality...

Answer (score 2):

No, not in general. Try imagining two non-orthogonal, non-parallel lines in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (which obviously intersect at a single point). For most points, projecting onto one line, then onto the other, will not even produce a point in the intersection, let alone the closest such point!